# R: How to draw a level plot with log tick scales

Tags: r, plot, contour, lattice, levelplot

I would like to draw a level plot with x and y scales as a log10 ticks.

For example, I have a normal level plot like this.

```
x <- 10*1:nrow(volcano)
y <- 10*1:ncol(volcano)
filled.contour(x, y, volcano, color = terrain.colors, plot.title = title(main = "Volcano topolgy", xlab = "Meters North", ylab = "Meters West"), plot.axes = { axis(1, seq(100, 800, by = 100)); axis(2, seq(100, 600, by = 100)) }, key.title = title(main = "Height\n(meters)"), key.axes = axis(4, seq(90, 190, by = 10)))
```

[image]

But, the x and y scales are not log tick scales. I found the other library "latticeExtra" with log tick scale function. For example, using the same x and y from above I can draw the log ticks, but cannot fill the contour data.

```
library(lattice)
library(latticeExtra)
xyplot(y ~ x, scales = list(x = list(log = 10), y = list(log = 10)), xscale.components = xscale.components.log10ticks, yscale.components = yscale.components.log10ticks)
```

[image]

How can I draw a level plot with log tick scales? I would like to plot scatters on the level plot later on as a log location.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an alternative using `lattice` and `latticeExtra`

```
library(lattice)
library(latticeExtra)

xx <- 1:nrow(volcano)
yy <- 1:ncol(volcano)

levelplot(
  x = volcano,
  xlim = range(xx),
  ylim = range(yy),
  scales = list(x = list(log = 10), y = list(log = 10)),
  xscale.components = xscale.components.log10ticks,
  yscale.components = yscale.components.log10ticks
)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

if you want to keep using `filled.contour` you can logtransform the `x` and `y` data directly and adjust the axes accordingly with a custom `axis` statement, but it's not very elegant (the `base::plot` `log = "xy"` parameter sadly doesn't do anything in `filled.contour`):

```
x <- log(10*1:nrow(volcano))
y <- log(10*1:ncol(volcano))
filled.contour(x, y, volcano, color = terrain.colors, 
               plot.title = title(main = "Volcano topolgy", 
                                  xlab = "Meters North", 
                                  ylab = "Meters West"), 
               plot.axes = { axis(1, at = log(seq(100, 800, by = 100)), labels = seq(100, 800, by = 100)); 
                                                axis(2, at = log(seq(100, 600, by = 100)), labels = seq(100, 600, by = 100)) }, 
               key.title = title(main = "Height\n(meters)"), 
               key.axes = axis(4, seq(90, 190, by = 10)))
```

[image]
you can also try if `ggplot2` with `scale_y_log10()` and `scale_x_log10()` would work for you, see [this question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25788727/filled-contour-vs-ggplot2-stat-contour).